# How to run a lot of functions asynchronously with different parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have an async func like `deleteItem(id)` and an array of `ids`.
How can I run the same function asynchronously at the same time for each id?

Does `Promise.all` helps in this case?

deleteItem - removes a file from google cloud storage

Comment: It all depends on what `deleteItem()` actually does. You did not post that, however.

Comment: `Promise.all` would help to get notified when all the parallel async functions are done. Note however that JavaScript is single threaded. Only I/O operations that "leave" the JS environment can actually be parallelized. (you can always spawn more processes of course). So as Pointy said, it really depends on what `deleteItem` does.

Comment: deleteItem() executes a promise to remove a file from google cloud storage

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var ids = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];
var myParallelTasks = [];

//push all delete functions in an array
ids.forEach( function( id )
{
    myParallelTasks.push( deleteItem( id, function(callback)
    {
       callback();
    })
    );
}

//wait for all to finish
async.parallel( myParallelTasks, function()
{
    // all done
    console.log( "All files were deleted " );          
});
```